Show two functions are identical on a domain
Let $U$ be a simply connected region, such that $U\subset \mathbb{C}$. Let $p,q\in U$ such that $p \neq q$. And $f,g$ be biholomorphic map from $U$ to $U$. Prove if f(p) = g(p) and f(q) = g(q), then f(z) = g(z) for all z in $U$.
My first thought is to use Schwarz's Lemma together with Riemann mapping theorem and apply identity theorem.
But I dont even know how to begin. So I want to see if I can prove this when $U$ is the unit disc. In that case I can set $h(z)=f(z)-g(z)$. And define $\phi_p(z)=- \bigg(\dfrac{z-p}{1- \overline{p}z}\bigg)$. Because $|p|<1$ we know this $\phi_p$ is a biholomorphic function from unit disc to unit disc and in addition we know that $\phi_p $ takes $0$ to $p$. Hence $h\circ \phi_p(z)$ is a holomorphic function that takes $0$ to $0$ on the unit disc. Now, by Schwarz Lemma we can conclude $|h(\phi_p(z))|\leq |z|$ and $|(h\circ \phi_p(0)) ^\prime|\leq 1$. Similarly, $|h(\phi_q(z))|\leq |z|$ and $|(h\circ \phi_q(0)) ^\prime|\leq 1$. I want to use these facts to conclude the problem. I've been working with this for hours and wasnt able to get to anywhere. Could someone tell me if I am heading to a right direction? If not could you give some hints ? Thanks!

Map everything to the unit disc and note that if a disc automorphism $h$ has two fixed points they cannot be both in the open disc unless $h$ is the identity since otherwise the equation $h(z)=z$ is either linear (so one root when $h(z)=e^{it}z$ but not identity) or quadratic with product of the roots having modulus $1$ so either both are on the unit circle or one is inside and one outside
